# Weird results in c

Tags: c, string

I'd like to ask you about my prog. The main purpose of this one is to fill the "result" array with data collect from "tab1" and "tab2" arrays. Could anybody check, why does results are so weird? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void laczenie(char tab1[],char tab2[])
{
int i;
char* result =(char*) malloc(100*sizeof(char));

for(i=0;i<30;i++)
{
    if(tab1[i] != '\0') tab1[i]==result[i];
     else if (tab2[i] !='\0')tab2[i]==result[i];
     else printf(" ");

}
for(i=0;i<30;i++)printf("%c",result[i]);
free(result);
}


int main() 
{
char x[10]={'n','a','p','i','s','1'};
char y[10]={'n','a','p','i','s','2'};
//char x[10] = {"napis1"};
//char y[10] = {"napis2"};
laczenie(x,y);

return 0;}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Comment: you are never assign anything to result!` tab2[i]==result[i]` checks only if the value are the same!

Comment: partly because `==` `!=` `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to LihOs answer above this block looks wrong:

```
if(tab1[i] != '\0') 
  tab1[i]==result[i];
else if (tab2[i] !='\0')
  tab2[i]==result[i];
else printf(" ");
```

Don't you mean to assign the value in `tab1[i]`or `tab2[i]` to `result[i]`like this?

```
if(tab1[i] != '\0') 
  result[i] = tab1[i];
else if (tab2[i] !='\0') 
  result[i] = tab2[i];
else printf(" ");
```

Also using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) like in the loops: `for(i=0;i<30;i++)` is pretty bad practice, you should probably be using a constant for the size value (which you could then use in both the loops and in the array declarations. And why loop to 30 when the arrays is 10 elements only?

Comment: I think, this is the real problem. It s never assigning anything to the result array.

Answer (score 3):

In your function you check for null-terminating character:

```
if(tab1[i] != '\0')
```

but where is null-terminating character here?

```
char x[10]={'n','a','p','i','s','1'};
```

Try:

```
char x[7]={'n','a','p','i','s','1','\0'};
```

---

Also note that `tab1[i]==result[i];` compares `tab[1]` with `result[i]`, if you want to assign the `result[i]` to `tab1[i]`, use assignment operator `=`:

```
tab1[i]=result[i];
```

Comment: And, what does tab1[i] **==** result[i]; mean? I guess it should be tab1[i] **=** result[i];

Comment: @billhoo: Well spotted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(tab1[i] != '\0') 
result[i] = tab1[i];
else if (tab2[i] !='\0') 
result[i] = tab2[i];
else printf(" ");`
```

This is still wrong as by the time you assign tab2 to result i will be already at 6 so you will have to use two for loops i suppose for assign tab1 and tab 2